# Moving instance variable from partial to helper

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to display a town name in my navigation, depending on the town I am requesting from the model. The following code works, but I am mixing logic in my view which I know is wrong and I haven't been successful in accessing the `@town` instance variable from my `TownsController`.

Can someone lead me down the road to enlightenment in a situation like this? Should I be using a helper? How do I access it in my `_header.html.erb` partial?

```
<li class="name">
   <% @towns = Town.all %>
   <% @towns.each do |t| %>
      <h1><%= link_to "#{t.name}", '#', id: "logo" %></h1>
   <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is _header.html.erb part of the layout? If so, i would advice you to move this logic to helper, if not all the controllers would need to set the @towns instance variable.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def town_names
    Town.all.collect(&:name)
  end
end
```

And in your view call the town_names. I think you want each name to be in an `li` element. I have changed the code accordingly.

```
<% town_names.each do |name| %>
     <li class="name">
       <h1><%= link_to name, '#', id: "logo" %></h1>
     </li>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: You should not be doing ActiveRecord queries in a view helper. Instead, do set the `@towns` instance variable in all required controller actions using a `before_filter`.